# What part of speech do ordinal numerals belong to?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Consider the below sentence.

> On the first of February, the meeting shall take place.

What part of speech does the ordinal numeral 'first' belong to? I am aware that under some analyses, ordinal numerals are considered a part of speech in their own right; however, I am not convinced by this. For one thing, the addition of a noun such as 'day' renders 'first' an adjective. What is more, to the extent that I know, ordinal numerals do not have a distinct set of 'rules', in the same way adjectives or verbs do.

Comment: The ordinal numbers, "first, second, third" etc are adjectives, as evident from the fact that they can be modified by the adverb "very".

Comment: @BIllJ I caution against using that test unless people can reliably distinguish between *very* as adverb and *very* as adjective. Nouns can also be modified by *very*: "the very top of the mountain," "the very man we were looking for," "on this very spot." *The first*, as a noun, may still be a noun like these other words even if it is modifiable by a form of *very*: "The very first of February."

Comment: One may speak of a bill being due on the fifteenth. I can't imagine "the very fifteenth".

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "He left on the very first of the month".

Comment: How about *the very fifteenth*? A special rule for *first*, then?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Of course it's possible in the right context.

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster shows "first" as being either adjective, adverb, or noun. In that use it is functioning as a noun, the object of the preposition "on".

[M-W *first*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/first)

1 : one that is number one in a series — see Table of Numbers
2 : something that is first: such as
a : the first occurrence or item of a kind
b : the first forward gear or speed of a motor vehicle
c : the highest or chief voice or instrument of a group
d : an article of commerce of the finest grade
e : the winning or highest place in a competition, examination, or contest

Comment: Yes, the NP "the first of February" is object of "on, but "first" is a fused modifier-head NP, understood as "**first day** of February". "First" is thus an adjective here.

Comment: This would be the traditional answer: "the first," "a first," and "firsts" are all noun phrases. It would help to highlight what in the definition supports your answer: is this an instance of 1 (number one in a series, the first of February) or 2a (the first item in a kind)? Both?

Comment: In the use in question, it's most like number 1.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty "First" is **not** a noun here, but an adjective. Read my comment above. Think "first day", where "day" is not expressed but understood. Grammarians call it 'fusion' of modifier and head.

Comment: @BillJ  If what is represented by *first* is a fused modifier noun phrase, it doesn't make any more sense to call it an adjective than to call it a noun.

Comment: You're missing the grammatical point. "The first" is an NP consisting of "the" as  determiner and "first" as an adjective functioning as modifier-head. It's an adjective because it functions as a modifier of the fused head. Elsewhere "first" would be followed by a noun as in "first day", where it is clearly an adjective. It's no different to "the poor", again a fused modifier-head, where "poor" is an adjective, not a noun. You need to get up to speed by studying 'grammatical fusion'. Unfortunately, the question is closed, so I can't post a detailed answer.